# recursion with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to rewrite my urls in the form of

```
localhost/myapp/view/something or 
localhost/myapp/crud/something
```

to

```
localhost/myapp/view.pl?view=something or
localhost/myapp/crud.pl?action=something
```

all other request should be mapped like this:
  localhost/myapp/login to
  localhost/myapp/login.pl

I tried it with this .htaccess file but i get a recursion if i enable the last
RewriteRule, i don't get why because i protected it with a RewriteCond.
This is my first .htacces mod_rewrite file so please be patient with me ;)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?crud/([^/]*)$    /myapp/crud.pl?action=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?view/([^/]*)$    /myapp/view.pl?view=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond $1                     !^/(view|crud)$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)$            /myapp/$1.pl [QSA]
```

Update:

I removed the leading / and added [L] flags now i get the following error in apache's error.log:

```
[Mon Jul 09 11:55:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /srv/http/myapp/myapp
```

New File:

```
RewriteRule ^crud/([^/]*)$    myapp/crud.pl?action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)$    myapp/view.pl?action=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1                !^(view|crud)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$         myapp/$1.pl [QSA]
```

Comment: check out mod_rewrite flags - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags maybe the [L] will help you.

Comment: This is an impressive firest attempt. :-)  The leading `/?` are not required for `.htaccess` rules.  Ditto loose the leading `/` on the replacements. (Read up on "Per Directory" syntax).  Likewise the cond regexp should be `!(view|crud)`.  Plus add the [L] flags.

Comment: Ok i got rid of the leading / and added the [L] flags, now i get this in error_log:  /srv/http/myapp/myapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your URIs contain myapp, I am assuming that this is in `DOCroot/myapp/.htaccess`, in which case your base is /myapp/ and all rewrites are relative to this.  (Look for "Per Directory" in the documentation.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /myapp/

RewriteRule ^crud/([^/]*)$    crud.pl?action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)$    view.pl?action=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$            $1.pl             [L,QSA,NS]
```

I've also changed the last rule to rewrite UTIs for /myapp/xxxxx (any word) to /myapp/xxxxx.pl as long as it doesn't map to a file or directory name.

Also look at [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules), and in you case since you have access to the Apache config, consider enabling `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` in your system config (or `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` if you are using Apache 2.4).

Comment: can i choose every prefix as RewriteBase? For example rewrite /app to /myapp ?

Comment: Read the doc'n on RewriteBase.  You should only have 1 per .htaccess file giving the base URI which gets to this directory.  Also go through that debugging tips Q that I linked to, which explains when and which .htaccess files are executed.  You would normally rewrite /app to /myapp in the `DOCroot/.htaccess` file.